# resize parent div after using transform: translate on a child tag

Tags: css, tailwind-css

So after changing the position of a div using transform translate, the parent div does not resize accordingly to fill the white space. Any advice would be appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<p>
Distance from top
</p>
<section>
  <div class="container mx-auto my-8">
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-4 px-4 font-bold">
      <div class=" bg-green-200 p-10 aspect-square w-7/12">
        <p>Lorum ipsum !</p>
      </div>
      <div class="-translate-y-16 self-end bg-slate-200 p-10 aspect-square w-7/12">
        <p>Lorum ipsum !</p>
      </div>
      <div class="-translate-y-32 bg-green-200 p-10 aspect-square w-7/12">
        <p>Lorum ipsum !</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<p>
Distance from bottom
</p>
```

Comment: That's not what a `transform` does. It's **entirely** visual. So if you want the parent to change you have to actually move the child.

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried moving the element using position relative, but this gave me the same result.

Comment: @Oguzcan I think I find it

Comment: How did you move it? Can you put your attempt into your question?

Comment: @AHaworth `class="relative -top-16"` However this did not work, the solution was posted and accepted. It used margins instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ❌ I tried the `translate` way but not work,
- ❌ I tried the `position` way and still doesn't work.
- ✅ but with the negative `margin` trick, is working!

> `-mt-16`, `-mt-32` class solve it,
>
> `mt` means `margin-top` in plain CSS
>
>  and if you add `-` prefix, means negative value.
>
> and that it, solved!

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<p>
  Distance from top
</p>
<section>
  <div class="container mx-auto my-8">
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-4 px-4 font-bold">
      <div class="bg-green-200 p-10 aspect-square w-7/12">
        <p>Lorum ipsum !</p>
      </div>
      <div class="-mt-16 self-end bg-slate-200 p-10 aspect-square w-7/12">
        <p>Lorum ipsum !</p>
      </div>
      <div class="-mt-32 bg-green-200 p-10 aspect-square w-7/12">
        <p>Lorum ipsum !</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<p>
  Distance from bottom
</p>
```

> if there is a space between the text and content is because of the `container` class, but is solved. (see `Distance from bottom` text in your example and in my mine, huge improvement)